# Backtranform lsmeans in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, emmeans

I have created a simple linear regression model in R where I have log transformed the response. The independent variable is categorical with 80 levels. Then I use emmeans for pairwise tests. How can I backtransform the emmeans to have the same scale as the response (not the log scale)? I use the emmeans package in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just

```r
summary(emmeans(...), type = "response")
```

? There is a [vignette on transformations and link functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html)

e.g.

```r
library(emmeans)
m1 <- lm(log(mpg) ~ factor(cyl), mtcars)
summary(emmeans(m1, ~cyl), type = "response")
```

```
 cyl response    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   4     26.3 1.268 29     23.9     29.0
   6     19.7 1.190 29     17.4     22.3
   8     14.9 0.636 29     13.6     16.2
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Note that if you use `pairs(emmeans(m1, ~cyl), type = "response")` it will give you the pairwise ratios, but notes that the tests are performed on the log scale (as they should be)

Comment: Thank you, i have seen that but I do not understand why summary nu8ll = log(35) in (emm.src, infer = TRUE, null = log(35), type = "response")

Comment: A follow up question: What if I use Box cox transformation for the response? How can I backtransform emmeans?

Comment: that's probably a separate question, and harder: I don't think emmeans has anything built-in for back-transforming BC.  (See `?emmeans::make.tran`, and search for that in the vignette ...)